# Error 403 web scraping python beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

'''

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url_,headers=headers)
```

'''
I am trying to **scrape** this website "https://allegro.pl/uzytkownik/feni44/lampy-przednie-i-elementy-swiatla-do-jazdy-dziennej-drl-255102?bmatch=cl-e2101-d3793-c3792-fd-60-aut-1-3-0412"
Everything was working good till yesterday, but suddenly I get 403 error.
I have used proxies/VPN but still the error persists.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping

Answer (score 0):

When scraping a website, you must be careful of the website's anti-DDOS protection strategies. One form of DDOS is submitting many load requests at once via refresh, which can increase a server's load and hinder its performance. Using a web scraper does exactly that as it goes through each link, and so the website can mistake your bot as a DDOS'er and block it's IP address, making it FORBIDDEN (error 403) to access the website from it's IP address.

Usually this is only temporary, so after 12 hours or 24 hours (or however long the website sets a block period) it should be good to go. If you don't want to avoid a future 403 FORBIDDEN error, then consider sleeping for 10 seconds between each request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i tried with different ip address(using VPN and proxies) as well and shows same error!

Comment: Changing IP may not be sufficient. Imagine you're collecting user reviews of a product on a merchant site. And you have to switch from one page to another to get them all. After the first X pages you are blocked. You go on a proxy in Pakistan, and you ask for the X+1 page of the same product. Well, they can detect it.

Comment: But it may be something else in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some proxy services like [Bright proxy](https://brightdata.grsm.io/create). They have more than 72million+ proxies. I think this issue will resolve on rotating the proxy and useragent.